# Can't call a method from another class

Tags: c#

I try to call `myCar.FormatMe()`, but it doesn't show. I don't know why. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
namespace SimpleClasses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.Make = "BMW";      
            myCar.FormatMe();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string FormatMe()
        {
            return string.Format("Make: {0}", this.Make);
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

There is no output in your code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Make = "BMW";      
        Console.WriteLine(myCar.FormatMe());
    }
}

class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string FormatMe()
    {
        return string.Format("Make: {0}", this.Make);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Hanaka you may consider accepting one of the answers posted here to mark it as answered! :0

Answer (score 4):

**Orphaned Strings and Reading Instead Of Writing**

You are returning a string from your `FormatMe()` function but aren't actually doing anything with it :

```
myCar.FormatMe(); // This will return your value, but it isn't being stored
```

Additionally, you are calling the [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method which actually expects input *from* the user as opposed to outputting it to the user.

**Store Your Variable and Write It Out**

Consider storing it in a variable or directly passing it as a parameter to the [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) method to be sent as output :

```
// This will store the results from your FormatMe() method in output
var output = myCar.FormatMe();
// This will write the returned string to the Console
Console.WriteLine(output);
// You can now read it here
Console.ReadLine();
```

or :

```
// Write the output from your FormatMe() method to the Console
Console.WriteLine(myCar.FormatMe());
// Now you should be able to read it
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Example**

You can [see an interactive example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aVNp3Q) and its output demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either wrap your function call in a call to `Console.WriteLine()` or have `FormatMe()` do the same thing.

What you are doing with your function call is simply returning a string, but not doing anything with it, like assigning it to a variable or passing it to another function as a parameter. Hence, it "does nothing," because you haven't done anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

you should get the value from `FormatMe()` or simply print it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Car myCar = new Car();
     myCar.Make = "BMW";           
     Console.ReadLine(myCar.FormatMe());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for little late; and i'm not sure about the acceptance of this kind of answers; Please forgive me if it is not the right way.

Let's have a look at the problem with the help of an example. That, you are asking for something(`here it is a formatted string`) to a named person(here it is `car`). and the question is give me a formatted sting(`FormatMe()`). everything is fine up-to this.

Whats next? If everything is fine(means there is no issues in the function) to give you the formatted string, the person will give you the result. This too okay in your case(function returned the formatted string perfectly).

What you need to do at this time? you need to collect the product from the respective person.unfortunately you forgot to collect them, but you are trying to deliver it to another person. this is happening in your case.

So what to do? you need to collect the product, the formatted string before you delivering it to the console. that is:

```
string formattedString =myCar.FormatMe(); // collecting formatted string
Console.WriteLine(formattedString); // delivering it to the console
```

Or you can collect them on the way to the console like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(myCar.FormatMe()); // delivering it to the console
```

Comment: You can't output to console using ReadLine

Comment: @techspider : You suggestion helps me to improve my answer Thank you very much. Take a look into the updates